# Issue refreshing a view of a row in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I want to update a view of the recyclerview when a notifyItemChanged has been called. The thing is that I don't want to refresh the entire row but only the view of the row. (to avoid the blinking effect of the row)

There is a method called notifyItemChanged(int, payload obj).

Can I use that to achieve that? If so how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you show us some code, like your recyclerview adapter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I found how to update only the specific view of a row in RecyclerView.

(1) Override **onBindViewHolder(Recycler.ViewHolder VH, int position, List payloads)** in the adapter

(2) Inside that onBindViewHolder method,

```
if(payloads != null && !payloads.isEmpty() && (payloads.get(0) instanceof  customObject)){
   // update the specific view
}else{
   // I have already overridden  the other onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int)
   // The method with 3 arguments is being called before the method with 2 args. 
   // so calling super will call that method with 2 arguments. 
   super.onBindViewHolder(holder,position,payloads);
}
```

(3) So to notify data change and update the view, need to call the **notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)**. Need to pass the customObject(model which holds the data) as the payload object.

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(i, obj);
```

**Note : Need to disable the RecyclerView's ItemAnimator(By default it is enabled). Otherwise payload object will be empty.**

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

or

```
((SimpleItemAnimator)recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

**UPDATE: I used this method recently without disabling the ItemAnimator. So no need to disable ItemAnimator. - (recyclerview-v7:25.4.0)**

[for further reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463136/recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemchanged-never-passes-payload-to-onbindviewholde)

Comment: Very nice. This issue caused me headaches since it was creating two ViewHolders even though I only wanted to change one item via `notifiyItemChanged`

Comment: Perfect. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to get the view of updated item:

```
View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
if (v != null){
    //update your view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an **ArrayList of items**, and it is fed to the RecyclerView adapter. Let it be something like this.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(items);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now as I can see you want to insert items into the RecyclerView and call notifyItemChanged(int position) method to add only the single item.

For this let's say you have changed the value of item in position 0. That's the first item in the list.

Now the proper usage of the method notifyItemChanged(int position) will be

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
```

**This means, the adapter will update the recyclerview with the new value in 0 position.**

Comment: not to insert an item. I need to change an already existing item of the array list

Comment: Then instead of calling notifyItemInserted(int position) call notifyItemChaged(int position). I've updated the answer.

Comment: yes, I'm doing that already. but it refreshes the entire row causing a blinking effect. I want to avoid that by only refreshing the specific view of thet row.

Comment: Are you calling setAdapter() method again?

Comment: no, just change a boolean value of the object and calling notifyItemChanged. I debugged it and it goes through the onBindViewHolder again and resetting the data to views again.